# $\mathcal{B}=\{\{x\} \cup \{z \in \Bbb J : |z-x| < \varepsilon \} : x \in \Bbb R, \varepsilon >0\}$. Is $\mathcal{B}$ a base for topology on $\Bbb R$?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\Bbb J= \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$ and $\mathcal{B}=\{\{x\} \cup \{z \in \Bbb J : |z-x| < \varepsilon \} : x \in \Bbb R, \varepsilon >0\}$. Show that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for some topology $\tau$ on $\Bbb R$. Is $(\Bbb R, \tau)$ regular?

For any $x \in \Bbb R$ there exists $B \in \mathcal{B}$ for which $x \in B$ so $\mathcal{B}$ is a cover for $\Bbb R$. If $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ and $b \in B_1 \cap B_2$, then $b\in(\{x\} \cup \{z \in \Bbb J : |z-x| < \varepsilon ) \cap (\{x'\} \cup \{z' \in \Bbb J : |z'-x'| < \varepsilon )$. Do I have to consider cases now? It seems that I would get four of them here? If $b \in \{x\}$ and $\{x'\}$, then $b=x=x'$. If $b \in \{x\}$ and $\{z' \in \Bbb J : |z'-x'| < \varepsilon \}$, then what can I do with these situations? It must be that $b = x$ and that $z'\le x\le x'$ then?

Comment: I think, even for the case $b=x=x'$ is not completely obvious since you still need to write $B_3$ as an element in $\mathcal B$ such that $x\in B_3\subset B_1\cap B_2$

Answer (score 1):

For $i\in \{1,2\}$ let $b_i=\{x_i\}\cup (\,J\cap (x_i-e_i,x_i+e_i)\,)\in B.$

Suppose $y\in b_1\cap b_2.$ Then $y\in (x_1-e_1,x_1+e_1)\cap (x_2-e_2,x_2+e_2).$ So there exists $e_3>0$ such that $$(y-e_3,y+e_3)\subseteq (x_1-e_1,x_1+e_1)\cap (x_2-e_2,x_2+e_2).$$

Now $y\in b_3=^{def}\{y\}\cup [J\cap (y-e_3,y+e_3)]\in B.$

Since $y\in b_1\cap b_2,$ we have $$b_1\cap b_2\supseteq \{y\}\cup [J\cap (x_1-e_1,x_1+e_1)\cap (x_2-e_2,x_2+e_2)]\supseteq$$ $$\supseteq \{y\}\cup [J\cap (y-e_3,y+e_3)]=b_3.$$